# imgur over ssl: Connection refused

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, imgur

Currently imgur fails to serve images over ssl:

```
> LANG=C curl -v https://i.stack.imgur.com/yurfY.png
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.197.236.143...
* connect to 54.197.236.143 port 443 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 54.221.248.15...
* connect to 54.221.248.15 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to i.stack.imgur.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to i.stack.imgur.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Without ssl the images work.

[image: Example with ssl]

[image: Example without ssl]

Comment: https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/841747846055501824

Comment: but.. but.. TLS is the new one.. SSL is an outdated term

Comment: Both aren't working for me, ssl regardless

Comment: @KevinB: Yeah. It's impossible to add non-TLS-images. :-}

Comment: @Floern: I've updated the tag wiki a bit; you're welcome to start the discussion about switching tag and synonym. :-)

Comment: YAY! It's all better now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an issue with Cloudflare / Imgur.  Somehow the DNS was pointed at the wrong CNAME.

> This looks to be resolved. The only action we took was to disable and re-enable the service in cloud-flare, on the supposition that the technical outage they were having earlier might have had an impact (and so resetting would hep kick their system). The images and links provided in this email thread appear to be working again. Please let us know if you continue to have issues,