# Why do I see a Spanish featured blog post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, internationalization

Why do I see a Spanish blog post in the Community Bulletin module across the Stack Exchange network?

[image]

While I appreciate the multilingual approach to Stack Overflow, my Spanish is only  good enough to [order something in a restaurant](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19845/13538), not to read blog posts. I guess this is the same for most users here. I'd like to have links to non-English blog posts not appear in the Community Bulletin – if an exception is built in for (in this case) [es.SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (and maybe [spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)), that's fine.

Comment: [imgur support seems to be broken at the moment.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292351/295232) If you can't see the image, look at the yellow block at the right side of this page.

Comment: @AdamLear are you sure it's a [bug]?

Comment: Yes. Something got overlooked in the last blog system migration. Not 100% sure *what*, but this is a regression from how international blog posts were working before.

Comment: OK, thanks. I usually don't pay attention to blog posts, so I don't know how the system is *supposed* to work.

Comment: Unless you use one of the international SO sites, you had no way to know we had these blog posts for a long time now. :)

Comment: No, I don't, except for flagging spam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about that. We recently moved our company blog to a different hosting platform (again!), and that caused some issues both with in-English posts being sync'd to community bulletins on localized Stack Overflow sites and with non-English posts written by community managers on those sites being propagated to community bulletins network-wide.

A fix is out in production now, though community bulletins are cached. They should self-heal in a few hours. Please let me know if you see any other CB weirdness after that.

Comment: Is the new hosting platform WordPress?  Looks like it from reading the source, but you were supposedly migrating away from it...

Comment: @NormalHuman So, funny thing about that... Turned out that WordPress is a massive pain to maintain and host on-prem for us [given the low activity on community blogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow), but is actually pretty alright for non-technical contributors. I'm not up on all of the details, but as far as I know we ended up with hosting at a third-party provider who takes care of the infrastructure maintenance for us and consolidating company blogs from Jekyll and Hubspot into one location.

Comment: Or in short, we should expect many more bugs.

Comment: And [now it appears in the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5876454#5876454). Same bug?

Comment: can we get an rss feed that does not include these for blog.so? Because having a bot regularly post these into a site main-room is just begging to ignore the bot, even when the post would be relevant ...

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Maybe! I'll talk to the folks running the blog to see what's possible there.

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow The main blog feed should exclude non-English posts now.

Comment: @AdamLear thanks very much :)