# How is WordPress used to create the site stackoverflow.blog?

Tags: support, design, stack-exchange, blog, community

I don't have enough experience in WordPress. All I know is we can install themes in it, make customization in the themes, create your own theme, and use it.

I was reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) and found that [stackoverflow.blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) is made on WordPress. I'm also going to build a blog section in one of my sites and was planning to create everything on my own. But after reading about **stackoverflow.blog**, I think using WordPress will be the much easier task.

I would like to know how it is made. I mean did they choose some theme and customized it? Can you share which theme it was?

Or did they create their own theme for WordPress? If they are designing a complete theme by their own then why use WordPress? Couldn't they make it completely on their own without WordPress?

What is the use of WordPress here on the StackOverflow.blog site?

Comment: But they know very well, that the opensource things are good. They use a lot of them. Would it be their decision, I think the SE had been written in Java and PostgreSQL today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that is like asking them to show the source code.

Comment: eh, if Joel was doing it? I suspect still the current stack. If Jeff was doing it? ROR, postgres (?) and docker.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard No, it isn't. I'm just asking how did they use WordPress to build the site so that I will also follow that criterion. I'm just asking if they create their own design, then why to use WordPress? Why they preferred WordPress.

Comment: @peterh SE sites are made in C#. And using WordPress just because it is opensource may not just be the reason for choosing it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: I still don't know why downvotes and why the question is closed.  :/

Comment: Can someone give me the link to defined scope *about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network*.

Comment: @Siraj I didn't say that they selected wordpress because it is opensource. I said that they selected wordpress because it is good, and they know it.

Comment: I said "like". That's something custom built by SE developers, and not meant for others to use.

Answer (score 2):

In summary? Its simple, it works, and someone else handles the actual management of it. The use of wordpress, in theory, is that it gives an avenue for SO corporate to talk about products outside the SE sites - though, [I've personally been a little grumpy at them in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303019/stackoverflow-blog-isnt-that-great)

These days? They pay someone to run it. Its probably a simple theme that was either designed in house, or done by the folks who run it and not much else.

*Historically* there were per site blogs - like [blog.superuser.com](http://blog.superuser.com), but the "burden" of running a different stack and managing it didn't make sense, either for per site blogs or for SE, so they were eventually killed off.

SE also experimented with Jekyll, before the current incarnation - it didn't work that well for [non technical folk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300294/is-the-jekyll-blog-dead)

Despite a slightly spotty reputation - *unlike* a homebrew solution, as long as you're judicious about your plugins, and keep it up to date, running and maintaining a blog on wordpress is simple, and well understood, and we're saving valuable time that could be spent on core site features, or at least new products from SE.

Creating or modifying a theme is also a lot less work than building an entire blog from scratch, and its a excellent, if not somewhat wholesale use code, and you can customise just look and feel, or add features you need, without needing to redesign the wheel.

As an aside, setting up wordpress, from the web and database server up is an excellent way to learn your way around a linux server.

Comment: *an excellent way to learn your way around a linux server* ... you mean how to get lost and confused between all directories, config, tooling ...

Comment: What better way is there to learn? ;p

Comment: There is no end to it ...

Comment: *exactly* DOWN THE RABBITHOLE WE GO!